.NET Core 8 appsettings.json not defaulted when env specific file is used
I've been working in Java the past few years and starting back into .NET now. I'm struggling with getting my configs working as I'd like.
I want to have this structure:

appsettings.json: default settings that are env agnostic
appsettings.local.json: local specific config overrides
appsettings.dev.json: dev specific config overrides
appsettings.stage.json: stage specific config overrides

The issue I'm running into is that when the appsettings.local.json file is used (or any other env specific file), then the base values in the appsettings.json file aren't loaded even if the appsettings.local.json file didn't override them.
Config setup code:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = builder.Configuration;

configuration
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

appsettings.json:
{ 
...    
"Mctv": {
  "Port": "8080",
  "CORS": {
...

appsettings.local.json:
{
...
  "Mctv": {
    "Run-Environment": "local",
    "CORS": {
...

Note that the Port setting isn't specified in the appsettings.local.json file, I want it to just use the value in the appsettings.json file.
How do I set this up so that the env agnostic config in appsettings.json is honored when not overridden by a value in an env specific config file?
Right now when I run with
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "local"

only the values in the application.local.json file are used.
EDIT
I've seen some posts online that state to do something like this:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = builder.Configuration;
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

configuration
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", reloadOnChange: true, optional: false)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", reloadOnChange: true, optional: true)
    .Build();

But I get the same behavior when I tried that.

It might not be the configuration issue as I cannot reproduce your issue. I start a new default Asp.net core MVC project and use your configurations and the values show as expected. The port remains 8080 while the CORS are overwritten. To narrow down the issue you could start a brand new project to compare the settings. Or it might be the issue of how you observe the behavior, I test the values this way : var config = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(); Console.WriteLine($"Port: {config["Mctv:Port"]}"); Console.WriteLine($"CORS: {config["Mctv:CORS:AllowedOrigins"]}");

My configurations are the same as your code snippets found online.

Make sure you have set "Copy to output directory" as "Copy always"/"Copy if newer" for all settings file:


Without it, they won't be copied alongside compiled files, and thus the code won't find it.
As a debugging process, you could specify that environment specific settings file is not optional and observe if exceptions are thrown.
Here's reference SO post.
